# Android XML: Custom button drawable without duplicate xml for each button state?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-drawable

I'm trying to make a custom_button, and what I have so far is this, two states (pressed and enabled) have their own shape with a border:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<selector xmlns:android='http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android'>

    <!-- Pressed -->
    <item android:state_pressed='true'>
        <layer-list>
            <item> <!-- Border -->
                <shape
                    android:shape='rectangle'>

                    <solid android:color='@color/Foreground'/>
                </shape>
            </item>

            <item android:bottom='2dp' android:top='2dp' android:left='2dp' android:right='2dp'> <!-- Color -->
                <shape
                    android:shape='rectangle'>

                    <solid android:color='@color/WidgetSoft'/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

    <!-- Enabled -->
    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item> <!-- Border -->
                <shape
                    android:shape='rectangle'>

                    <solid android:color='@color/Foreground'/>
                </shape>
            </item> <!-- Color -->

            <item android:bottom='2dp' android:top='2dp' android:left='2dp' android:right='2dp'> <!-- Base Color -->
                <shape
                    android:shape='rectangle'>

                    <solid android:color='@color/Widget'/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

</selector>
```

This works, but it specifies two identical buttons where only the colors are different. When I add the other button states and more look 'n feel this is gonna be more and more duplicating. Is there a way of having a *base_button.xml* drawable where the basic same-for-every-button attributes can be set and a *custom_button.xml* where attributes specific to the button state can be set in their corresponding  tag?

Below is a pseudo-example of what I mean, but I don't know how to make that a reality. *custom_button.xml* handles the button states and *base_button.xml* specifies the basic characteristics of the button.

custom_button.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<selector xmlns:android='http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android'>

    <!-- Pressed -->
    <item android:state_pressed='true' android:drawable='@drawable/base_button'>

        <!-- SET GLOBAL_BORDER_COLOR TO '@color/btnPressedBorder' -->
        <!-- SET GLOBAL_BASE_COLOR TO '@color/btnPressedBase' -->

    </item>

    <!-- Enabled -->
    <item  android:drawable='@drawable/base_button'>

        <!-- SET GLOBAL_BORDER_COLOR TO '@color/btnEnabledBorder' -->
        <!-- SET GLOBAL_BASE_COLOR TO '@color/btnEnabledBase' -->

    </item>
    
</selector>
```

base_button.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<layer-list xmlns:android='http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android'>
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape='rectangle'>

            <solid android:color= GLOBAL_BORDER_COLOR />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:bottom='2dp' android:top='2dp' android:left='2dp' android:right='2dp'>
        <shape
            android:shape='rectangle'>

            <solid android:color= GLOBAL_BASE_COLOR />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Is this even possible in XML? I came across xsl:variable online, but couldn't get it to work. Any suggestions on how to this or alternative ways of achieving the same result are much appreciated!

Comment: Xsl is  part of xslt.  The xml used by drawables doesn't support that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [ColorStateList](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList) for the colors. Define a *ColorStateList* for the widget's border and one for its fill. The state of the widget will be pushed down to the *ColorStateList* where the color will be selected. You can then define a drawable as follows:

**base_button.xml**

```
<layer-list>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape='rectangle'>
            <solid android:color="@color/widget_border" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom='2dp'
        android:left='2dp'
        android:right='2dp'
        android:top='2dp'>
        <shape android:shape='rectangle'>
            <solid android:color="@color/widget_fill" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The *ColorStateLists* will look like this. (Forgive the color selection.)

**widget_fill.xml**

```
<selector>
    <item android:color="@android:color/holo_red_light" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_light" android:state_enabled="true" />
</selector>
```

**widget_border.xml**

```
<selector>
    <item android:color="@android:color/black" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:color="@android:color/holo_red_light" android:state_enabled="true" />
</selector>
```

And finally, the sample layout file:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:background="@drawable/base_button"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Putting it all together, it will look like this:

[image]